# When should `new` be used in Go?

Tags: go

It seems pointless to be used in primitive language constructs, as you can't specify any sort of values

```
func main() {
    y := new([]float)
    fmt.Printf("Len = %d", len(*y) ) // => Len = 0
}
```

For stucts it makes a *bit* more sense, but what's the difference between saying `y := new(my_stuct)` and the seemingly more concise `y := &my_struct`?

And since anything you create is based on those primitives, they will be initialized to the said zero values. So what's the point? When would you ever want to use `new()`?

Sorry for the very-beginner question, but the documentation isn't always that clear.

Comment: "what's the difference between..." `new` is used on a type. `&` is used on a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `new` for slices and maps, as in your code example, but instead you must use the [`make` command](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make): `make([]float, 100)`

Both `new(MyStruct)` and `&MyStruct{}` do to the same thing, because Go will allocate values on the heap if you get their address with &. Sometimes the code just expresses it intent better in one style or the other.

Go does not have built-in support for constructors, so usually you would wrap the call to `new` into a function, for example `NewMyStruct()` which does all the necessary initialization. It also makes it possible to initialize private fields or hide the struct behind an interface, to prevent users of the object from directly messing with its internals. Also evolving the structure of the struct is easier that way, when you don't need to change all of its users when adding/removing/renaming/reordering fields.

Comment: Regarding using new, I guess that's a compiler error that makes that code valid, compilable code? Or is something else going on?

Comment: I suppose calling new on slices allocates something, but it's not a usable slice. Slices and maps require some special initialization, and the make call does that. (I think that it's a deficiency in the language design that make is needed for some built-in types, but that's just the way it's now. Maybe if generics or constructors are added at some point, make would not be needed.)

Comment: I see. So I guess the answer is, you don't.

Comment: No, you *can* use `new` on slice and map types. `new` initializes the memory pointed to to be the zero value for the type (all types have a zero value), which is `nil` for slices and maps. So `new` on a slice or map type simply creates a pointer to `nil`. `x := new([]float)` is the same as `var temp []float; x := &temp`

Comment: Slight correction. Go allocates on the heap if the pointer escapes the function. It does this by performing escape analysis and allocating appropriately. Just using new or the & operator is not enough to cause the value to be allocated on the heap

Answer (score 0):

`make` does only work for maps, slices and channels and composite literals like `type{}` work only for structs, arrays, slices, and maps. For other types, you'll have to use `new` to get a pointer to a newly allocated instance (if you don't want to use a longer `var v T; f(&v)`).

I guess this is useful if you want to initialize a struct:

```
typedef foo struct {
    bar *int
}
v := foo{bar: new(int)}
```