# setting values in a new declartion

Tags: go

Is it possible to include values in the declaration of a `new` type.

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

func main() {
    v := new( Vertex{ 0, 0} ) // Like so
    fmt.Println( v )
    // Instead of :
    v = new(Vertex) 
    v.X, v.Y = 12, 4 // extra line for initializing the values of X and Y 

    fmt.Println( v )
}
```

Or because go makes the "Vertex{val, val} " a literal value instead of a basic Vertex type it's not possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can declare a `new` object whenver you want, just my the keyword `new`. Google for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need "new", you can simply write:

```
v := Vertex{1,2}
```

If you want a struct with all members set to the **zero value** of their types (e.g., `0`
for ints, `nil` for pointers, `""` for strings, etc.), it's even simpler:

```
v := Vertex{} // same as Vertex{0,0}
```

You can also only initialize some of the members, leaving the others with their zero value:

```
v := Vertex{Y:1} // same as Vertex{0,1}
```

Note that with these v will be a variable of type Vertex. If you want a **pointer** to a Vertex, use:

```
v := &Vertex{1,2}
```

Comment: those are two different types. Using new will give you a pointer to vertex and the one you use will give you a vertex.

Comment: you're right, sorry for overlooking that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: To my understanding now, `new` is only useful for when you want to store an empty data type to a pointer. Correct?

Comment: In that case, you can use `v:=new(Vertex)` or `v:=&Vertex{}` - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129068/when-should-new-be-used-in-go?rq=1

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew: new is only useful for types like `int` where you cannot do `&Vertex{}`. Always use `&Vertex{/* init if needed */}` and never new.

Comment: @Volker Very helpful, thanks! I find it peculiar that the official go lang tour shows that as an example "new(Vertex)"

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew The tour shows a lot (almost all) of the language. But you'll find `&Vertex{1,2}` one slide earlier than new :-)